# RESET timer after each match

Tags: timer, stm32, reset

I want to have an LCD which turns on with a button press and after some time(for example 10 seconds) if button do not pressed again, LCD turns off.

I want to implement this with STM32L433 and basic timer TIM6.
Note that for some reason I need to use freeRTOS in this program which is not related to LCD operation.

How can I reset timer every time button is pressed to avoid from turn off LCD ?

best!

Comment: @Alex F, How can I implement this functionality with freeRTOS timer?

Comment: @Alex F, Are you sure one Tick duration is exactly 1 ms? I test it on board and it seems it last more than that! My clock frequency is 1 MHz (Does it depend on system clock?)

Comment: FreeRTOS provides soft timers, which are probably the best fit for this job.

Comment: @Tagli, Would you explain more? Are you think about timer which we use for freeRTOS clock?

Comment: See https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Software-Timer-API-Functions.html

Comment: FreeRTOS soft timer is a good idea, or you can use a low power timer (I think STM32L4 have them) LPTIM, and then use the macro '__HAL_LPTIM_RESET_COUNTER'

Comment: Or you can use '__HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER' on a basic timer to reset the counter value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.Yes there is plenty of choices.But I am wondering WHY osDelay() do NOT works correctly in freeRTOS?
would someone explain this in details please?